# assigning function to variables and assigning variables to functions(?) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, var

I'm learning javascript by dissecting a few scripts written by other people that I have used before (stackoverflow is essential to this!). This bit of code (and I cut a lot from the middles to make the code easier to read, and all comments are mine) comes from [fullCalendar.js](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), a jquery plugin.

I'm not sure what the author is doing here:

```
function EventManager(options, _sources) { //called using .call()
    var t = this;

    t.isFetchNeeded = isFetchNeeded;  //?? assign the function "isFetchNeeded" to the variable (not the value returned by the function)??

    var trigger = t.trigger;    //?? namespace??
}

function View(element, calendar, viewName) {
    var t = this;   

    function trigger(name, thisObj) {
        return calendar.trigger.apply(
                 calendar,
                 [name, thisObj || t].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2), [t])
        );
    }
}
```

First, my guess is that `this.foo=bar` is assigning the function "bar" to the variable called "isFetchNeeded" within the current object (not yet sure why you'd do this. speed?).

Second, the line `var foo=this.bar` has me stumped. It looks like it might be some namespace magic.

Am I correct in thinking about the first line? and what's the next line doing?

Thanks

Comment: honestly, you need a good Javascript primer but not quite. Let me recommend you Spencer Tippings' Javascript in 10 minutes

Comment: There are no "namespaces" in javascript, only object properties. And you need to distinguish those from variables.

Comment: @Bergi: You're right, of course. I was thinking "scope" but wrote "namespace"

Comment: @NannuoLei: Thanks for the reference. It does look like a good resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.foo = bar` assigns the value of `bar` (whatever it may be) to the object's member named `foo`.  This can indeed be a function definition along with a host of other things.

What `var trigger = t.trigger` does is declare a variable named `trigger` in the scope of the `EventManager` function.  There are other functions defined in a lower scope, namely `pushLoading` and `popLoading`.  These are not object members, so using `this.trigger` inside of those functions would not work.  The `var trigger` declaration makes it accessible in these functions.

I don't claim to be anywhere close to the best JS programmer ever, so I can't say whether what he's doing makes a ton of sense or not, but you can see how `EventManager.js` is actually used (in `Calendar.js`):

```
EventManager.call(t, options, eventSources);
var isFetchNeeded = t.isFetchNeeded;
var fetchEvents = t.fetchEvents;
```

He does not actually create an `EventManager` object, but he calls its constructor with the `Calendar` object.  `Calender` *does* have `trigger` defined, which is why `var trigger = t.trigger` works inside of `EventManager`.  Similarly, the line

```
var isFetchNeeded = t.isFetchNeeded;
```

In `Calendar.js` acquires the `isFetchNeeded` method "back out of" `EventManager` and allows it to be called in the `Calendar` scope.

Comment: This is a good explanation. Thanks! I wasn't thinking in terms of lower scope. And now I see why the author called the first type "exports" and the second type "imports".

Answer (score 0):

The variable `this` references the context the function was called in.  In this case (assuming the code is being run in a web browser) is the `window` object. The first line simply assigns the function `isFetchNeeded` to be a method of the `this` object.  The second line assigns the value of `this`'s member variable `trigger` to a variable local to the function `EventManager`.

Comment: Neither is `this` a variable, nor is it likely that it refers to the global object - those functions are constructors.

Comment: Note that `The variable this references the context the function was called in` is incorrect. The value of a function's `this` parameter can be any value (in strict mode) or any object otherwise. It's set entirely by the call and is completely independent of the execution context the call was made from.